# Why the cpu frequency shows differently in Win10 task manager and system properties?

Tags: windows-10, cpu

Why the below CPU frequency shows are different? I am using Win10.

In Task Manager
[image]

And in System Property

[image]

Comment: The base frequency of your CPU is 1.90 GHz and the boost frequency is 2.90 GHz.  Windows is reporting the based frequency as the specifications of the CPU but also reports the current frequency the CPU is running at which for you, at the time of the screenshot, is 2.5 GHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CPU is an 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300I CPU @ 1.90GHz' with '@ 1.90GHz' as a part of that name. Which means that the processor's base frequency<sup>1</sup> of your CPU is 1.90 GHz. But here the CPU is telling the system that it's running at 2.63GHz.

For some other CPU's I would have said its overclocked, but your CPU model has a feature known as Turbo Boost<sup>2</sup> which enables it to automatically overclock to a higher yet safe frequency based on certain conditions.

The Turbo Boost frequency for your CPU is 2.90 GHz, which means your CPU can attain that frequency under certain conditions but is currently running at 2.63GHz.

Also, Windows calculates the max frequency of your CPU to be 2.50GHz as different algorithms are used to measure processor speed.  For example, the algorithm used by Intel in its branded maximum speed is different than the algorithm used by Task Manager to directly measure the speed of the CPU.  You can use other processor utilities, such as the Intel Processor Identification Utility or CPU-Z, for additional processor speed measurements.

Also note that Hyper-V as well as VMware is reported to interfere with the clock speed calculation of Task Manager.

I'd stick with CPU-Z for measuring CPU frequency as it's calculation algorithm is much better.

---

#### Notes:

1. Processor Base Frequency describes the rate at which the processor's transistors open and close. The processor base frequency is the operating point where TDP is defined. Frequency is measured in gigahertz (GHz), or billion cycles per second.
2. Intel® Turbo Boost Technology accelerates processor and graphics performance for peak loads, automatically allowing processor cores to run faster than the rated operating frequency if they’re operating below power, current, and temperature specification limits. Whether the processor enters into Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 and the amount of time the processor spends in that state depends on the workload and operating environment.

#### Sources:

1. https://goo.gl/obtiWG
2. https://goo.gl/MUtlOr
3. https://goo.gl/a9Ga3h
4. https://goo.gl/FotxKq

Answer (score 1):

That "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300I CPU @ 1.90GHz" is not showing the CPU frequency, it's showing the CPU's full, internal name. Intel is saying that the CPU is designed to run at a maximum, continuous speed of 1.90 GHz. It's actually running at a higher speed than that right now either because it's overclocked or because it is able to run at a higher speed due to low loading and/or low heat.